# Go to another form on click of button in NetBeans

Tags: swing, button, jframe

I have 2 forms `Main` and `Add`, created in NetBeans. `Main` form contains a button in it. What I want is *to show `Add` and remove `Main` on click of this button.* How to do this?

Comment: Try this: 1. Add actionListener to button. 2. In actionPerformed() method show Add and remove Main form. For more help provide some more details.

Comment: To show the Add form call setVisible(true), setVisible(false) can be used to hide Main form.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
Add addPage=new Add();
addPage.setVisible(true);
```

for the button envent of the Main